# Parsing JSOUP table

Tags: android, jsoup

I want parse a HTML table but i don't understand how get the values.
I have this table:

```
<table class="aircraftInfoGrid">
            <tbody>
              <tr class="first">
                <td class="iconContainer">
                  <span class="icon aircraft"></span>
                </td>
                <td colspan="2">
                  Aircraft<span class="right" id="aircraftIcaoVal">(A320)</span><br>
                  <span id="aircraftVal" class="strong">Airbus A320-214</span>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="iconContainer"></td>
                <td colspan="2">
                  Registration<span class="right" id="hexVal">(4CA212)</span><br>
                  <span id="registrationVal" class="strong"><a class="regLink" data-reg="EIDEB">EI-DEB</a></span>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="iconContainer">
                  <span class="icon cloud"></span>
                </td>
                <td>
                  Altitude<br>
                  <span id="altitudeVal" class="strong hasTooltip" data-tooltip-align="left" data-tooltip-value="2,438 m">8,000 ft</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                  Vertical Speed<br>
                  <span id="vspdVal" class="strong">0 fpm</span>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="iconContainer"></td>
                <td>
                  Speed<br>
                  <span id="speedVal" class="strong hasTooltip" data-tooltip-align="left" data-tooltip-value="469 km/h, 291 mph">253 kt</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                  Track<br>
                  <span id="trackVal" class="strong">267°</span>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="iconContainer">
                  <span class="icon satellite"></span>
                </td>
                <td>
                  Latitude<br>
                  <span id="latVal" class="strong">51.593</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                  Longitude<br>
                  <span id="lonVal" class="strong">-0.5887</span>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="iconContainer"></td>
                <td>
                  Radar<br>
                  <span id="radarVal" class="strong">N-EGLM2</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                  Squawk<br>
                  <span id="squawkVal" class="strong">7651</span>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

I don't understand how parse it: This is my code:

```
doc = Jsoup.connect("http://x.com/EIN1C6/367d800").timeout(10*1000).get();
org.jsoup.nodes.Element tabella = doc.getElementsByClass("aircraftInfoGrid").first();

Iterator<org.jsoup.nodes.Element> iterator = tabella.select("td").iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()){   
    iterator.next().text();
    System.out.println("TITLE: "+iterator.next().text());
}
```

and i get this output:

```
    05-24 07:03:18.270: I/System.out(2088): TITLE: Aircraft
05-24 07:03:18.270: I/System.out(2088): TITLE: Registration
05-24 07:03:18.280: I/System.out(2088): TITLE: Altitude
05-24 07:03:18.290: I/System.out(2088): TITLE: 
05-24 07:03:18.290: I/System.out(2088): TITLE: Track
05-24 07:03:18.310: I/System.out(2088): TITLE: Latitude
05-24 07:03:18.310: I/System.out(2088): TITLE: 
05-24 07:03:18.320: I/System.out(2088): TITLE: Squawk
```

can you make an example for me?
I want parsing all value of this table... Thank you in advance!

EDIT: SPAN VALUE:

```
    05-24 11:08:49.240: I/System.out(3679): TD Value : Aircraft
05-24 11:08:49.240: I/System.out(3679): TD colspan : 2
05-24 11:08:49.240: I/System.out(3679):     SPAN Value : 
05-24 11:08:49.240: I/System.out(3679):     SPAN class : right
05-24 11:08:49.240: I/System.out(3679):     SPAN id : aircraftIcaoVal
05-24 11:08:49.240: I/System.out(3679):     SPAN Value : 
05-24 11:08:49.240: I/System.out(3679):     SPAN id : aircraftVal
05-24 11:08:49.240: I/System.out(3679):     SPAN class : strong
05-24 11:08:49.240: I/System.out(3679): ************************************
```

Comment: This link will give you some idea: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12466542/2915785

Comment: Yes but i don't know how get this:                   <span id="aircraftVal" class="strong">Airbus A320-214</span>

Comment: bro check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9446348/2915785 then, it will surely help you :) best of luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want span details just nest the for loops. for e.g the below program prints out all values of this table. I just copied the gien html into a file so the program reads from a file. You could change that to your URL.

```
import java.io.File;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Attribute;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;


public class JsoupParser {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File input = new File("t.html");

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8");

        int index = 0;
        for (Element td : doc.select("td")) {
            System.out.println("************************************");
            System.out.println("Row " + (++index));
            System.out.println("************************************");
            printValuesAndAttributes("TD", td);
            for(Element span : td.select("span")){
                printValuesAndAttributes("\tSPAN", span);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void printValuesAndAttributes(String prefix, Element el) {
        System.out.println(prefix +" Value : " + el.text());
        for(Attribute attr : el.attributes()){
            System.out.println(prefix + " " + attr.getKey() + " : " + attr.getValue());
        }
    }

}
```

If you want the entire span tag html then use the toString method or if you want the value use like above as el.text()

```
for (Element span : doc.select("td span")) {
    System.out.println(span);
}
```

Comment: Thank you but i want get this:
                  <span id="aircraftVal" class="strong">Airbus A320-214</span>

Only Airbus A320-214

Comment: What do you want in that case? the complete span tag?

Comment: Yes i want get this value: Airbus A320-214 - All values from table

Comment: That is what it prints. All values and attributes. Can you share the link?

Comment: Updated the answer.. Try the second loop it print the entire span tag. is that what you are looking for? Basically the toString method of Element object print the entire html.

Comment: Thank you... but i want only this value= Airbus A320-214. It is here:                   <span id="aircraftVal" class="strong">Airbus A320-214</span> .
And later i want this value: <span id="lonVal" class="strong">-0.5887</span>

String1 = Airbus A320-214
String2 = -0.5887
etc...

Comment: 05-24 14:42:51.670: I/System.out(3914): OUTPUT: <span id="aircraftVal" class="strong"></span> but....the text  "Airbus A320???? where is?? in the table exist: <span id="aircraftVal" class="strong">Airbus A320-214</span>

Comment: The site is flightradar24, is possible parse this?? a flight

Comment: Yes. It should be parsable but based on what information you need. The flight details are listed via an ajax call and json response. So you may have to use jsoup to get the json response and the parse it via a json parser like gson or jackson.

Comment: I have not figured out how to do it. If you use JSOUP the result is null. I want parse the details of the flight, speed, wind, latitude, longitude ... can you help?

Comment: In this site the flight details are polled via javascript ajax calls. So after page load they invoke an ajax call to http://db8.flightradar24.com/zones/full_all.js?callback=pd_callback&_=1401126256649 to get the flight details. If we zoom into a particular part it uses a seprate js say europe_all.js.. This essentially returns a json containing all flight details. First we need to get this json and then parse it to get flight id and then again invoke http://bma.fr24.com/_external/planedata_json.1.4.php?f=36c0ae5&callback=flight_data_service_cb&_=1401126256666 to get the details you want

Comment: Uhm... thank you! and is possible execute a parsing for get the data? use only JSON?

Comment: Yes. But that json is huge. You might have to limit to a select flight.

Comment: for example... i Want get data , speed , altitude, latitude, longitude, of this flight.. http://www.flightradar24.com/NAX7011/36bfb8f - i don't understand please :( can you make me a example?

Comment: Answer updated to you other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23849141/parsing-flightradar24-and-jsoup/23876757#23876757

Answer (score 0):

i am doing like this

```
Document doc1;
        doc1 = Jsoup.connect("http://localhost:8080/WebApplication1/").get();
        String title = doc1.title();
        //int i = 0;
        //System.out.println("title is: " + title);
        //System.out.println("AAA");
        Elements tr = doc1.select("tr");
        //Elements td = doc1.select("td");

        //System.out.println(td.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < tr.size(); i++) {
            if (!(tr.get(i).child(1).text().contains("Court NOT in session!"))) {
                System.out.println("Court Number"+tr.get(i).child(0).text());
                System.out.println("Sl Number"+tr.get(i).child(1).text());
                System.out.println("List Type "+tr.get(i).child(2).text());
            }
            //System.out.println(i);
        }
```

For selecting elements qith particular attribute you refer to jsoup selectors at following link

https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html