# Parsing FlightRadar24 and JSOUP

Tags: android, parsing, jsoup

Hi guys i want parse a flight on flightradar24.com
I have tried with JSOUP and Android but results is null.

http://postimg.org/image/6hdmp4hgv/

I have read... JSOUP doesn't support dinamyc webpages.
There is a solution for this?
I want get Latitude, longitude, and more
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this site the flight details are polled via JavaScript ajax calls. So after page load they invoke an ajax call to http://db8.flightradar24.com/zones/full_all.js?callback=pd_callback&_=1401126256649 to get the flight details. If we zoom into a particular part it uses a separate JavaScript file, say for Europe they use europe_all.js. This essentially returns a json containing all flights details including the speed the altitude etc. this is maintained as a key-value pair and key being the flight id and value an array of details.

First we need to get this json and then parse it to get flight id which is the key and then again invoke http://bma.fr24.com/_external/planedata_json.1.4.php?f=36c0ad6&callback=flight_data_service_cb&_=1401126256666 to get the details flight trails, the name start time, end time, status etc.. The trails is given as an array of latitude and longitude and the first two elements points the current position.

For both url the ending digit is the `System.currentTimeMillis();`. For the second url the argument "f" is actually the flight ID which is the key of first json. So the below program will parse these two json and give you the data.

I used full_all.js which gives all the flight information which is really huge. To limit the network call i put a break in the for loop. So this program only prints the details of first flight. If you remove the break you'll get all details of all flights but mid you that's like a 10000 calls.

The first json itself gives you enough information like the one given below. Its just one entry from first json and it says flight with id "36c0ae5", the registered key "0D05AD", current lat (25.54), lon (-99.24), speed 287, altitude 16650 ft, etc etc

```
"36c0ae5": [
    "0D05AD",
    25.54,
    -99.24,
    287,
    16650,
    354,
    "0610",
    "F-KBRO1",
    "A320",
    "XA-BIC",
    1401129559,
    "CUN",
    "MTY",
    "4O321",
    0,
    -1920,
    "AIJ321",
    0
  ]
```

Program

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

public class FlightDetails {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String allFlightsURL = "http://db8.flightradar24.com/zones/full_all.js?callback=pd_callback&_=" + System.currentTimeMillis();
        String allFlightsJsonString = getJsonString(allFlightsURL);
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonObject allFlightsJsonData = (JsonObject)parser.parse(allFlightsJsonString);

        String singleFlightUrl = "http://bma.fr24.com/_external/planedata_json.1.4.php?f=###&callback=flight_data_service_cb&_=";
        for(Entry<String, JsonElement> allFlightEntry : allFlightsJsonData.entrySet()){
            StringBuilder urlBuilder = new StringBuilder(singleFlightUrl.replaceAll("###", allFlightEntry.getKey())).append(System.currentTimeMillis());
            System.out.println(allFlightEntry.getKey() + " = " + allFlightEntry.getValue());
            String singleFlightJsonString = getJsonString(urlBuilder.toString());
            JsonObject singleFlightJsonData = (JsonObject)parser.parse(singleFlightJsonString);
            for(Entry<String, JsonElement> singleFlightEntry : singleFlightJsonData.entrySet()){
                System.out.println(singleFlightEntry.getKey() + " = " + singleFlightEntry.getValue());
            }

            break; // Breaking to avoid huge network calls.
        }

        System.out.println("Done");
    }

    private static String getJsonString(String allFlightsURL) throws IOException {
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) ((new URL(allFlightsURL).openConnection()));
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.connect();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(line);
        }
        return buffer.substring(buffer.indexOf("(") + 1, buffer.lastIndexOf(")"));
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, you are the best! it work fine :) but there is a problem. I have developed a android app and when tap on a flight into my app, how can obtain a ID ??? example: "36c0ae5" - I have only code of flight. Thank you! *** NB *** If we edit this link: http://www.flightradar24.com/FLIGHT_CODE example: http://www.flightradar24.com/BER7421 and press enterthe system generates an ID. how obtain this ID know ONLY  flight code?

Comment: It depends on how you display it in your android app. I assume in the site they display the flight icons using javascript and map api. So we may need to dig into that so as to find out how they add the onclick handler. Even if we find that out getting a handle on that onClick may not be easy. Also when i use url/FLIGHT_CODE it redirects me to main page.

Comment: hello if you try to access the URL / FLIGHT_CODE the main page will appear and left the details of that flight. But is this legal? http://www.flightradar24.com/terms-and-conditions/ *cit: Modify, reverse engineer, reverse assemble, decompile or hack into any of the software applications or related tools or utilities used by this Website;

Comment: Oops. Its not legal. By point to use license you can use it for personal use. So what we did is not a decompile or reverse engineering. So you can play around for just personal learning. But I advise to stay away since flight details are very sensitive.. ;)

Comment: Uhm... Thank you.... there is another site for this and is legal for show flight detail?

Comment: read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23886604/flightstats-api-parse
this is legal!!! can you help me please?

Comment: I don't know about the API. I'll just go through it and see. Will give you an update by evening. OK?

Comment: Its not completely free. It has a free evaluation version.  Check https://developer.flightstats.com/getting-started/pricing

Comment: Hey. I've gone through the API. Its fairly straight forward like the example given above. You just need to substitute with their urls. However I couldn't make a sample as to invoke those webservices you need to register for a free account and get appId and appkey. If you have a registered account please send me these to syams18@gmail.com and I could get you a sample program. I'm still confused form where you get the flight id. :)

Comment: Ok got it. If you don't have a particular flight or airport we may need to perform a series of calls. First get all airport details then get the flights from that airport, then for each flight get the status. Anyway it should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to read in the forum: 
http://forum.flightradar24.com/threads/24-API-access

Comment: Hi...thank u.. cit flightradar24: We do not offer any API access to this data. There aren't API for access info flights

Comment: Yes - please also read why - they do not want 3rd party usage of their data

Comment: is possible get data with HtmlUnit for dynamic webpages? so i can use this with flightradar?